# What does it mean for a red black tree to have same number of black nodes on all paths?

Tags: algorithm, red-black-tree

I don't understand what this condition means: *"For each node, all paths from the node to descendant leaves contain the same number of black nodes"*

Comment: What exactly is not clear about that? Is it what constitutes a black node? Or what constitutes a path from root to leaf? Or how to count black nodes? Can you clarify which concept you are really asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an example tree:

[image]

The statement says *"For every node..."*, so let's choose one such node as example, the root, node 13.

It speaks of *"descendent leaves"*. These leaves are the nodes with values 6, 11, 15, 22 and 27. They are descendents of our chosen node 13 and they are leaves, so *"descendent leaves"*.

*"all paths from the node to descendant leaves"* are thus the following paths:

- 13→8→1→6
- 13→8→11
- 13→17→15
- 13→17→25→22
- 13→17→25→27

Now count the black nodes on each of these paths:

- 13→8→1→6 has 2 black nodes (13 and 1)
- 13→8→11 has 2 black nodes (13 and 11)
- 13→17→15 has 2 black nodes (13 and 15)
- 13→17→25→22 has 2 black nodes (13 and 25)
- 13→17→25→27 has 2 black nodes (13 and 25)

So indeed, we see that *"all paths from the node to descendant leaves contain the same number of black nodes"*: exactly 2 for our example tree and selected node.

You can repeat this exercise for another node, for instance node 8. Then the *"descendent leaves"* are only nodes 6 and 11.

Now the results are:

- 8→1→6 has 1 black node (1)
- 8→11 has 1 black node (11)

And again, the statement is true. Actually, when the statement is true for the root, it is true for all nodes.